# не определен идентификатор "Т" в template

Tags: c++

Помогите разобраться, почему в этом коде для template min все определенно правильно, а для template calc выводит ошибку что  идентификатор "Т", не определен

[image: не определен идентификатор "Т" в template]

Среда разработки VS 2019

---

Код в тексте...

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> 
T min(const T x, const T y)
{
    return x < y ? x : y;
}

template<typename Т> 
void calc(const T a, const T b)
{

}

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Картинку в текст передайте и проверьте, что буквы не из разных языковых алфавитов

Comment: Попробуйте вместо T указывать что-то более предметное - прим. dogType

Comment: согласен! Но в данном случае... копировал текст из PDF книжки, разбирался с шаблонами, и почему-то в буфер, параметр T был скопирован, как русский символ... не ожидал такого подвоха, вот и возник этот вопрос....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скопировал ваш код в онлайн компилятор: [ссылка](https://ideone.com/LoY7cW) .

Ошибки компиляции:

```
prog.cpp:13:19: error: stray ‘\320’ in program
 template<typename Т>
                   ^
prog.cpp:13:20: error: stray ‘\242’ in program
 template<typename Т>
                    ^
prog.cpp:14:17: error: ‘T’ does not name a type
 void calc(const T a, const T b)
                 ^
prog.cpp:14:28: error: ‘T’ does not name a type
 void calc(const T a, const T b)
                            ^
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:22:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘calc(int, int)’
     calc(3, 4);
              ^
prog.cpp:14:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class> void calc(int, int)’
 void calc(const T a, const T b)
      ^~~~
prog.cpp:14:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:22:14: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<template-parameter-1-1>’
     calc(3, 4);
              ^
```

Вывод - буква "T" у вас левая, скорее всего русская. Вручную удалите все шаблонные буковки T и пропишите их явно английской клавиатурой. Я так сделал (3 буковки во второй функции, calc) и всё заработало.